How do you load a regtest wallet?
Running Bitcoin Core 27.0.0, how does one load a regtest wallet if the name of the wallet is unknown?
bitcoin-cli -regtest loadwallet <name?>

Steps I've tried

listwallets
No wallet is listed in regtest from what I can tell

Read wallet.dat
The wallet.dat file located at ~/.bitcoin/regtest/wallets/regtest can not be easily read since it's binary format



The name of the wallet is its filename, relative to the wallet datadir (~/.bitcoin/regtest/wallets).

I’m confused by "can not be easily read since it's binary format"? The loadwallet RPC would take care of the import when the right path is provided as long as the file is a Bitcoin Core wallet file, so what were you getting at with that sentence?

As the documentation for the loadwallet RPC describes, the syntax is:
loadwallet "filename" ( load_on_startup )

And it further specifies:
Arguments:
1. filename (string, required) The wallet directory or .dat file.

What’s not clearly specified in the documentation is that you are to provide the filename relative to the wallet directory ~/.bitcoin/regtest/wallets. It would be great if the documentation were improved in that regard.
listwallets returns the currently loaded wallets, so that’s why the wallet was not shown before it was loaded.

Part of my confusion is the machine that I am running bitcoin-cli is a different machine then the bitcoin node is on.  Am I specifying the wallet path that's on the bitcoin-cli client side or the wallet file location on the bitcoin node side?

bitcoin-cli just sends the command to the server. Yes, the filename is the name the wallet file has on the server.

From the bitcoin-cli client side, it worked to specify the path on the server side (problem solved).  However, interestingly specifying the filename wallet.dat from the client side returns an error "Failed to load database path" followed by the path it tried to load wallet.dat from.  When specifying the filename, the path it tried to load wallet.dat from was /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/regtest/wallets/wallet.dat however the path where wallet.dat exists on the server side is actually /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/regtest/wallets/regtest/wallet.dat.

I am specifying -regtest flag with every command bitcoin-cli command
